# Is it possible to decrease line spacing between rows in a docs table generated with pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ms-word

I am exporting a `dataframe` into a `Ms.word table`. When exporting it into `word`, there is a default `8pts` spacing between rows.
Would it be possible to change the preset spacing and decrease it? Or is there a way of changing the spacing settings after the table has already been imported into word?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import docx

columns = ['Number of Pts Measured', 'Percent Pass 3%/2mm', 'Comments' ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
        'Number of Pts Measured': total_points,
        'Percent Pass 3%/2mm': passing_percentage,
    }, columns=columns,
)

df = df.rename_axis('Field').reset_index()
df["Comments"] = ""
df["Field"] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df["Field"] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1
df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True) # drop last n rows

# open an existing document
doc = docx.Document(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\TableTwo.docx")

# add a table to the end and create a reference variable
# extra row is so we can add the header row
t = doc.add_table(df.shape[0]+1, df.shape[1])

# add the header rows.
for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
    t.cell(0,j).text = df.columns[j]

# add the rest of the data frame
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
        t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(df.values[i,j])
# save the doc

doc.save(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Table2.docx")
```

Comment: you should read documentation for `docx` because this problem has nothing to do with `pandas`

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html#tablestyle-objects